# Media folder not showing images in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco, media

I have migrated a umbraco site over. Hooked the databse up and everything is working fine but the images are not showing on the site and in the media folder.

I have set the permissions on the folder.

changed authentication on the folder to app pool.

tried changing virtualRoot to rootPath and rootUrl.

none of the above work. The files names are showing in the media window but no images (blank previews).

Funny thing is i can upload images now and there are showing so something to do with path.

hope someone can help. thanks

Comment: Did you copy over the contents of the media folder or was it empty until you started to upload new images?

Comment: no i copied over the complete media folder.

Comment: What is the url of the images that the browser is trying to load?

Comment: This is an example of the images

http://www.example.com/media/1181/logo.jpg

It should be this.

http://www.example.com/gt/site1/media/1181/logo.jpg

I just dont see where i need to update gt/site

as mentioned i did try tried changing the virtualRoot to rootPath and rootUrl.

but this only seems to work for new image that i upload.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to tell Umbraco that it's running in a virtual directory.

There is a setting in the `umbracoSettings.config` which you can read about here: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/config/umbracosettings/#notifications (search for **ResolveUrlsFromTextString**)

Set the following to true:

```
<ResolveUrlsFromTextString>true</ResolveUrlsFromTextString>
```